# Unable to figure out how to join chat

Tags: support, chat

I have been active on Ask Different for around a week now. Although I still end up making some mistakes, I am gradually managing to get a hang of the system.

This is my first time on any of the Stack Exchange sites, and I am enjoying my time on Ask Different. I have already managed to read and understand the help documents and FAQs.

While I managed to earn decent reputation points, one thing that I am still having hard time understanding is how the chat system works?

I may be missing something here (something really stupid), but I find myself unable to join the chat. Are the rooms invite only? Or are there public rooms too (for eligible members with enough reputation points)?

I am also not able to figure out the mechanism to create a new room and invite members.

This is the message that I get, every time I try to access Ask Different chat.

[image]

As I understand that 20 reputation points are needed to participate in chat and. I believe I am past that barrier, but I don't still see the option to join a chat room. Please help me through this.

Comment: Chat was tacked on afterwards. Let me see if I can locate the place where you need to make your “chat account” - once you have that account, then it gets tied to your account. Worst case, we’ll point you to the contact-us link at the bottom of each page...

Comment: Thanks @bmike. I was trying to figure out a way to reach you :). It occurred to me, asking out loud on meta could help!

Comment: Yes - this works great to ping site moderators - we all get a “ping” when a meta post arrives. Can you get in to any chat room anywhere on the SO side of things?

Comment: On a side note, does no reputation points gets awarded on Meta?

Comment: Correct, there's no (visible) reputation on meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of another moderator, I located a problem with your account.

Each person gets one “chat” account and it has a parent account on one of the sites. Your parent was on Stack Overflow and that account had 1 rep only. For whatever reason your other accounts with PLENTY of reputation didn’t get credited. I re-parented your chat account but I cannot clean up the original problem unless you request to merge those accounts.

If you don’t have other problems, no need to merge. If you do, just use the [Contact](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of any page or the link to the left.

- [Chat not working after account merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/chat-not-working-after-account-merge)

Comment: I have a fairly limited understanding of account merging, but as far as I can recall, I started by creating an account on Stack Exchange using my email. I have never merged 2 separate accounts into 1 if that’s what merging mean.

Comment: Yes - you would know you requested a merge. I’ve asked a couple other moderators. We should get an answer pretty soon, but there’s no reason for you to not use the contact form if you want. Once we’ve solved it - we can answer here and teach everyone how to fix if my guess was wrong.

Comment: Finally able to join chat room. Thanks bmike and @catija for your support and prompt response.

Comment: Not always does this happen, but when it does - it’s pretty cool. Chat between moderators is amazing as is teamwork.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. While I am new to this platform, I have spent years hanging out on Apple Developer channels on freenode IRC :)

Comment: Great result in the end. And we probably all learnt something new! :)